# Understanding of scopes in PowerShell for a C# developer

Tags: powershell, scope

I wonder why this don't work.
I think my understanding of scopes in PowerShell is wrong, it seems to be different as in c#.

Could someone please expain this?

`$SOAPAction` is in this case `null`, I expect that `$soap12` is `true`.

**Don't Work** (returns `false`)

```
$soap12 = $false;
if ($SOAPAction -eq $null)
{
    $soap12 = $true;   
}
$soap12
```

**Works!**  (returns `true`)

```
if ($SOAPAction -eq $null)
{
    $soap12 = $true;   
}else
{
    $soap12 = $false;
}
$soap12
```

Comment: What do you mean by "works" and "don't work" ? What are the results of your above bits of code? What is $SoapAction's value in both examples?

Comment: @GodEater you are right, I edit my question.

Comment: Your example is still missing something. This returns true: `$SOAPAction = $null;$soap12 = $false;if ($SOAPAction -eq $null){$soap12 = $true;}$soap12;` *(equals your Don't Work version but with initialized $SOAPAction variable)*

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I think there was a interdependency with other code in my script. I will try to figure that out and update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell the scope is used in the call of scripts blocks (functions) but not across the language blocks.

I think that the best for you is to read [About_Scopes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx).